# Unable to supply data from MYSQL on PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

**Okay so i am having problems displaying text from my MYSQL database. 
This is the file i am using to display**

```
<?php
require('db_Connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cust_Details";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Date</td><td>Comment</td><td>Amount</td></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = $row['Name'];
    echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$date."</td></tr>";
} 

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**The db_Connect.php file**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("MY DB HOST","MY DB USERNAME","MY DB PASS","MY DB NAME");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Here is a link to my PHPMyAdmin Screenshot**

http://postimg.org/image/afwlvb6gj/

Comment: what do you see when you do a: print_r($row); (inside the while loop)?

Comment: You immediately call `mysqli_close()` right after opening the connection! (last line of `db_Connect.php`). It is not usually needed to explicitly `mysqli_close()`. PHP will clean up that connection itself when it is no longer needed for the executing script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, you are closing your connection already in `db_Connect.php`. Remove the line containing `mysqli_close($con);` so that it looks like the following:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("MY DB HOST","MY DB USERNAME","MY DB PASS","MY DB NAME");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```